# Exported my Construct 2 game with Intel XDK (edit: Crosswalk); error message shows up. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: intel, construct

I just learned about the Intel XDK at Indiecade today, and I couldn't wait to get home to try a port of one of my Construct 2 games.  The game ended up working perfectly, aside from the fact that it has no sound when played on my Galaxy S5.  The Intel XDK Emulator plays the game with sound, but for some reason it doesn't work on my phone.  My volume is all the way up.  Are there any tips when importing C2 games with the Intel kit to make sure the sound is preserved?

One thing I might add is when I run the app, it gives me an error message as though I am trying to run it locally in my computer.  The actual message:

Alert: Exported games won't work until you upload them. (When running on the file:/// protocol, browsers block many features from working for security reasons.)

And then it auto-jumps to:

Application Error: The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

... as a matter of fact it stopped working altogether after the two error messages while I was typing this question.

Edit:  OK... so I exported it within the XDK as Crosswalk rather than simply Android, and the music now works.  However, the first error message I mentioned before still shows up.  I won't want this on all of my apps.  Any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

OK so this is what I did wrong:  When I exported through Construct 2, I did what I always do and exported as a web app.  What I should've done is export it as an Android app.  I seriously don't know why I didn't try this first but after exporting as Android and then using the Intel XDK to port it with Crosswalk, everything is peachy.

I found my answer here: https://www.scirra.com/blog/133/introducing-crosswalk-the-new-way-to-publish-to-android

Comment: Confirmed this as the answer. In the newer version of Construct, you export this for Cordova, then import to Intel XDK.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you found the answer here; I knew there would be a way :)
Just wanted to chip in as a follow-up, there is a webinar tomorrow for a much more in-depth tour of the XDK and its features - including crosswalk - than I was able to provide at IndieCade.  Let me know if it works out for you!

Thanks,
Brad

Webinar Link: http://l.intelswpartner.com/u.d?V4GjZxR-vxyrcx8RFF58HZ=33001

Comment: Mr. Hill!  Great to hear from you again!  I still have your card; was going to wait a couple weeks to send you an email and let you know that the XDK totally works with Construct 2.  I'll be at work all day tomorrow. Will there be a recording of your webinar available?  Edit: As of my last build, the Crosswalk integration uses a slightly older version of Cordova, which google play is flagging as a vulnerability.  Are you familiar with this issue?

Comment: Awesome; I'm not sure the webinar (of which I was a mere viewer) was recorded.. I'll have to look into it.  Shoot me an email and I'll let you know.  

As of the XDK build 2 days ago, the project templates use Cordova 3.5.1 - presumably this is what you mentioned.  The release notes are available at https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/release-notes-information-intel-xdk

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you export as a normal html5 and not as Cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'm calling other HTML offline and solved the problem with this post:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/adding-third-party-plugins-to-your-xdk-cordova-app

---

How Do I Reference cordova.js Script from My Project index.html File

To enable the use of Cordova plugins in an HTML5+Cordova project type, reference the cordova.js script file exactly once in your index.html file:

If your project contains more than one HTML file (or page) that will use Cordova APIs, you must include a reference to the cordova.js script file in each of those HTML files. It is highly recommended that you limit yourself to building single-page apps (SPAs) when creating Cordova applications. See this Cordova Best Practices article for more details. Also, note that the cordova.js file is a "phantom" file; it is not present in your project directory, but is added by the Cordova build system when your application is built (it is customized for your app as part of the build process).

---